# Trouble understanding relative imports

Tags: python-3.x

New to python, I know there's a bunch of similar questions to this but I'm still having trouble understanding how package importing works.

I have a directory setup like this

```
src/
|-- foo/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_foo.py
|   |-- foo.py
|-- bar/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- bar.py
|-- __init__.py
```

test_foo.py imports foo, which works fine. But then I want foo to import bar (a class). I've tried various combinations of

```
from ..bar.bar import bar
```

but I always get the error

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

What's the proper way to get relative import paths to work? I originally ran into this when dropping my tests in the same folders as their respective modules, and couldn't figure out how to get my imports correct. I know there's other ways of organizing my project, but still wanted to try to understand how to make this work.

Comment: From which file do you import your bar module?
Where is located your run.py file ?
How do you run it ?

Comment: Sorry updated the original post, had a filename wrong. I run test_foo.py, which imports foo, and then I want foo to import bar. My goal I guess would be to be able to import foo.py from anywhere and have all its dependencies work properly.

Answer (score 0):

When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory, the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and `sys.path` which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

However, you can add to the Python path at runtime:

```
# some_file.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```